# Multidimensional array to vector

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have following data:

```
let array1 = [[1], [2], [3]]
```

And I want to make it vector:

```
let result = [1, 2, 3]
```

Solution off the top of my head:

```
var result = [Int]()
for arrayOfArray in array1 {
  for value in arrayOfArray {
    result(value)
  }
}
```

Is there more elegant way to do this ?

Comment: Sub-array will only contain 1 element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` for that.

```
let array1 = [[1], [2], [3]]
let result = array1.flatMap { $0 }
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Check Apple Documentation on [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641503-flatmap) for more details.